# How to select all data in one column except one value?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2010

I wrote this c# code to select card_id from student info except one card_id, but i read from the net that except clause not work in access ... how i do this please help me?

```
ol_com.CommandText = "select [card_id] from student_info except select [card_id] from student_info where [card_id] = '"+update_st_card.Text+"'";
                reader = ol_com.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    up_st_lbl2.Text = "message";
                }
```

Comment: `"SELECT [card_id] FROM student_info WHERE NOT [card_id] = @cardID"`? And please, do not simply concatenate the sql statement like you do. Use the appropriate `Parameters` ([OleDbParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx)?).

Comment: please give me help how to use parameters? a peace of code

Comment: If you take a look at the page I linked to, there is an example at the bottom. What DB driver do you use? OleDb? ODBC?

Comment: i use OleDB driver and thank you know i understand it

Answer (score 3):

I think you are unnecessarily making a Complex Query.

It can be solved easily using `NOT IN`

```
ol_com.CommandText = "select [card_id] from student_info 
where [card_id] not in ('"+update_st_card.Text+"')";
```

Comment: Long time since I worked with Access. Does it have to be `x NOT IN y`, wouldn't `NOT x=y` work, too? +1 for "unnecessarily complex", btw.

Comment: your solution give me this error ... In operator without () in query expression '[card_id] not in '123''.

Comment: Can you please provide me the Error Details ?

Comment: ok it gives me this error .. see this link it is the image of error http://s24.postimg.org/53djcolh1/Capture.png

Comment: @HunarA.Ahmad I forgot the brackets. Now can you check?

Comment: konw the error is solved ... but in all time the if statement is true? can you solve this for me please?

Comment: That must be because you have written the logic in that way. if you explain me the exact scenario i can help you.

Comment: ok know i explain it ... i have form for inserting student info (student_name,college,dept,stage,card_id,mobile_no) i don't have any problem in inserting info but i have problem in updating student info.i use mobile_no or card_id for return student information to the textboxes , each textbox for one info,and in the same time i want user of project can also update mobile_no or card_id ... card_id and mobile_no are unique ... and when i click update button in all time give me message card_id or mobile_no is repeate?

Comment: luv can you help me please?

Comment: The Query is perfect according to the Question you asked. But we have to know how you are actually using it in your code. Please provide some code.

Comment: 'ol_com.CommandText = "select [card_id] from student_info where [card_id] NOT IN ('"+update_st_card.Text+"')";
                reader = ol_com.ExecuteReader();
                //current_card_id = Convert.ToInt32(update_st_card.Text.ToString());
                if ((string)reader["[card_id]"] == update_st_card.Text)
                {
                    up_st_lbl2.Text = "error this card_id is intered before";
                }//end check for card id repeate or not if

                else
                { //here i have update query}' // this is the code that i used?

Comment: Hey @Hunar, your are selecting the value which is not in the reader as you had already filter by where clause...

Comment: Please see below answer.

Answer (score 1):

You hav no problem in inserting so for update please try this simple one.
update_st_card.Text have one card_Id only.

```
ol_com.CommandText = "select [card_id] from student_info 
where [card_id] ='"+update_st_card.Text+"'";
reader = ol_com.ExecuteReader();
string str=string.Empty();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
  //Update here
    str="Update student_info set mobile_no='Your new value to set'
             where [card_id] ='"+update_st_card.Text+"'";

}
else
{
  //insert here
    str="Your Insert command";
}
ol_com.CommandText = str;
ol_com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem and we can use not in anywhere acess, sql server, nhibernate

```
ol_com.CommandText = "select [card_id] from student_info where [card_id] not in ( select [card_id] from student_info where [card_id] = '"+update_st_card.Text+"'");
reader = ol_com.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
   up_st_lbl2.Text = "message";
}
```

Comment: no it does not solve my problem i try this before ... and your code have an error in last parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use NOT IN

Your query could be written as,

```
select [card_id] 
from student_info 
where [card_id] NOT IN 
 (select [card_id] from student_info where [card_id] = '"+update_st_card.Text+"'")
```

Comment: i try this before but this doesn't work ... in all time the if statement is not?